# A theorem about convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, locally-convex-spaces

Assume that function $h(x)=f(ax+b)$ is a convex function. What can we say about the convexity of function $f(x)$?

My notes:

By taking the second derivative from both sides of eqaution $h(x)=f(ax+b)$ with respect to $x$, we have:

$h''(x)=d^2h(x)/dx^2=a^2 \times d^2f(ax+b)/d(ax+b)^2=a^2\times f''(ax+b)$

Since $h(x)$ is convex, $h''(x) \geq 0$.

Also, $a^2 \geq 0$. So, by taking into account the above-mentioned points, we can conclude that:

$f''(ax+b)\geq 0$

Here, the question is can we conclude that $f(x)$ is convex or not (Note that we do not know $f''(x) \geq 0$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need derivatives.

If $a=0$ then $h$ is constant and you can say nothing about $f$ (other than its value at $b$).

If $a \neq 0$ then $f(x) = h({1 \over a} y -{b \over a})$ which is a convex function composed with an affine function and hence convex.

Comment: Thank you for your note. But what s your idea about concluding that $f$ is convex because $f''(ax+b)\geq 0$?

Comment: How do you know that $f''$ exists?

Comment: For simplicity, we may assume that both $f$ and $h$ are differentiable functions.

Comment: If $f,h$ are twice differentiable, then if $a=0$ you can say nothing about $f$ and if $a \neq 0$ then you see that $f''(y) \ge 0$ for all $y$.

Comment: Right, but $f''(y)$ is not eqaul to $f''(x)$, so the quation is can we conclude that $f$ is convex?

Comment: Also, what if the domain of $f$ is not R?

Comment: If $f$ is defined on a restricted domain then clearly $h$ is defined on a restricted (but different) domain. You need to do a little work here.

Comment: Is it possible that function $h$ is not defined for some values of $x$ while function $f$ is defined? I am talking about the restricted domain.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: If $a \neq 0$ then the function $g(x) = ax+b$ is an invertible affine map. If $f$ has domain $D$ then $h= f \circ g $ will have domain $g^{-1}(D)$.